How to prove $p$ is in the confidence interval $[f-1/ \sqrt{n},f+1/ \sqrt{n}]$ where $f$ is one possible value of $\sum X_i /n$?
Let $X_1, ...,X_n$ be independent random variables such that $X_i \sim Bernoulli(p)$, $\forall i \leq n$
Let $F_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i /n$ and let $\omega_0$ be one event in the sample space of $F_n$ such that $\omega_0 = F_n^{-1} (\{f\})$.
By the CLT and the tabulated values of the normal distribution, we have, for big values of $n$:
$$ P\left( \frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}(F_n -p) \in [-1.96, 1.96] \right)=0.95$$
$$ P\left(|F_n - p|\leq1.96\sqrt{p(1-p)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) = 0.95$$
and, since $1.96\sqrt{p(1-p)}<1$, we have:
$$ P\left(|F_n - p|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \geq 0.95$$
If we denote by $S$ the set: $S=F_n^{-1} (\{p-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},p+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\})$, my question is then why does $$ \omega_0 \in S \iff p\in [f-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},f+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}]=I_c$$
implies that "$p$ is in $I_c$ with a likelyhood of at least $0.95$" ?
I understand that $\omega_0$ being a random event, it has a likelyhood of belonging to $S$ of at least $0.95$, and by the last above equivalence, $p$ is in $I_c$ with a likelyhood of at least $0.95$.
But in fact I don't know what a mathematical proof of it would look like.
I know how to evaluate the probability of an event, but not the probability of an event belonging to another event.
Thanking you in advance for the help.
Edit: As required by Amir, here's my explanation of $$ \omega_0 \in S \iff p\in [f-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},f+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}]=I_c$$:
$\omega_0 \in S \iff p-1/\sqrt{n} \leq F_n(\omega_0) \leq p+1/\sqrt{n} \iff 
f-1/\sqrt{n} \leq p \leq f+1/\sqrt{n}$

What is $f$? Is it the observed value of the sample mean? Are the RVs independent? Where have you seen $$ \omega_0 \in S \iff p\in [f-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},f+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}]=I_c?$$ Please first ask your question with required motivation and notation, and then add your efforts.
